# How to fix Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: arrays, offset, notice

In PHP 7.4 i'm getting this notice:
Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

```
if( $book_font ){
   foreach ( $book_font as $key => $font ) {
      if ( in_array( $font['face'], $all_google_fonts ) ) {
         self::options_typography_enqueue_google_font( $font['face'] );    
      }
   }
}
```

Notice for this line:

```
if ( in_array( $font['face'], $all_google_fonts ) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means in `foreach` loop, one or more value of `$font` is a boolean instead of an array.

One way to fix it is by using [null coalescing operator `??`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) like this:

```
if ( in_array( $font['face'] ?? '', $all_google_fonts ) ) {
```